# Can we prove nowhere differentiability of Brownian path via Karhunen–Loève coefficient?

Tags: reference-request, pr.probability, stochastic-processes, harmonic-analysis

This post is partly inspired by [Fourier Coefficients and Hölder Continuity](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/120335/fourier-coefficients-and-h%C3%B6lder-continuity).

Typical proofs of the nowhere differentiability of Brownian paths is by contradiction using binary expansion from real analysis. For example, Prop 11.
 of [S.Lally's notes](http://galton.uchicago.edu/~lalley/Courses/385/BrownianMotion.pdf).

But usually one can prove a function $f$ is nowhere differentiable  by examining their Fourier coefficients $\hat{f}$. For example [Simple Proofs of Nowhere-differentiability Weierstrass's Function and Cases of Slow Growth](http://people.math.aau.dk/~jjohnsen/Articles/WEBfiler/nowhere.pdf)

> Can we prove the nowhere differentiability (w.p.1) of Brownian paths by examining its Karhunen–Loève coefficients?
>
> Moreover, what is the relationship between Karhunen–Loève coefficients $\hat{X_t}$ and the smoothness of the path of an $L^2$ stochastic process $X_t$?
>
> If there is such a relationship, is this relationship similar to the relationship between Fourier coefficients and original function?

In response to Christian's comment,

> The Fourier coefficients don't look like the right thing to look at to
>   me if you want to establish that Brownian paths are *nowhere*
>   differentiable, since the FT responds to lack of smoothness *somewhere*
>   by lack of decay.

A natural thing to ask is that *what object characterizes/detects global non-smoothness in in situation?*

Comment: For a start, I think the Kolmogorov 0-1 law together with the fact that all the coefficients are smooth should get you that nowhere differentiability has probability 0 or 1 (because tweaking any finite number of your iid random variables will not change  the differentiability).

Comment: @NateEldredge Yes, we can observe that convergence of KL series is a tail event but do you mean that differentiability can be determined by the convergence rate of KL series itself and hence it's a tail event too?

Comment: No, I don't mean that - simply that, for each $N$, Brownian motion is nowhere differentiable iff the tail $\sum_{n=N}^\infty Z_n e_n(t)$ is nowhere differentiable (because the two differ only by the finite sum $\sum_{n=1}^{N-1} Z_n e_n(t)$ which is a smooth process).  So the event that Brownian motion is nowhere differentiable is in $\sigma(Z_N, Z_{N+1}, \dots)$ and $N$ was arbitrary.

Comment: The Fourier coefficients don't look like the right thing to look at to me if you want to establish that Brownian paths are *nowhere* differentiable, since the FT responds to lack of smoothness *somewhere* by lack of decay.

Comment: @ChristianRemling So what is the correct thing to look at here? And can't we discover nowhere differentiability by showing lack of decay with high probability?

Comment: No, not that easily because lack of decay of the FT just implies that the function is non-smooth *somewhere.* For me, the natural intuitive explanation of the fact is that typically $B_{t+h}\simeq h^{1/2}$.

Comment: @ChristianRemling Okay , got it, thanks!